# Detect OnTriggerExit when disabling gameobject

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

I am facing a very simple problem about Triggers, but I don't see any way to solve it. I just want the `OnTriggerExit` function to be called when an object **inside the trigger** gets disabled.

Here is the way to reproduce the problem in an empty scene :

1. Create a cube at (0,0,0) with a collider as trigger and the very simple following script :

   ```
   public class OnTriggerExitTest : MonoBehaviour
   {
       private void OnTriggerExit( Collider other )
       {
           Debug.Log( "Exiting : " + other.name );
       }
       private void OnTriggerEnter( Collider other )
       {
           Debug.Log( "Entering : " + other.name );
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create a sphere at (0,0,0) with a Sphere collider and a Rigidbody which does not use Gravity
3. Move the sphere out of the box, `OnTriggerExit` gets called
4. Move the sphere back to (0,0,0), `OnTriggerEnter` gets called
5. Disable the sphere, `OnTriggerExit` is **not** called
6. Enable back the sphere, `OnTriggerEnter` **is called**

[image: OnTriggerExitTest]

Obviously, I want `OnTriggerExit` to get called when I disable my sphere. Do you know any solution ?

I am using Unity 5.4.1f

I could use events in the `OnDisable` function of my sphere of course, but it's not very clean. I simply do not understand why `OnTriggerExit` is not called but `OnTriggerEnter` is.

Answer (score 2):

There technically is no reason why Unity could not call `OnTriggerExit` in your scenario. A likely reason would be however that the "other" Collider is null given that is has been destroyed and would muck up a lot of situations if not handled.

However, you could work around it by using `OnTriggerStay` instead. It should be called every frame, and the first time it isn't called in your scenario that could mean the other collider got disabled.